# iOS Web Service Not Working

Tags: objective-c, web-services

I have been following a tutorial (http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5) whereby I got the code to process a json web service (here is my web service: http://bit.ly/Y5430d)

So, I've changed my URL to my web service and the objectforkey to represent mine (I haven't changed any of the other variables). However, the unformatted json isn't coming through.

Is something wrong with my web service?

```
#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0) //1
#define kLatestKivaLoansURL [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.bushell.info/getResults.php"] //2

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface NSDictionary(JSONCategories)
+(NSDictionary*)dictionaryWithContentsOfJSONURLString:(NSString*)urlAddress;
-(NSData*)toJSON;
@end

@implementation NSDictionary(JSONCategories)
+(NSDictionary*)dictionaryWithContentsOfJSONURLString:(NSString*)urlAddress
{
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: urlAddress] ];
    __autoreleasing NSError* error = nil;
    id result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    if (error != nil) return nil;
    return result;
}

-(NSData*)toJSON
{
    NSError* error = nil;
    id result = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:self options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    if (error != nil) return nil;
    return result;    
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: kLatestKivaLoansURL];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}

- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
    //parse out the json data
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1
                                                         options:kNilOptions 
                                                           error:&error];
    NSArray* latestLoans = [json objectForKey:@"Latest lotto"]; //2

    NSLog(@"Latest lotto: %@", latestLoans); //3

    // 1) Get the latest loan
    NSDictionary* loan = [latestLoans objectAtIndex:0];

    // 2) Get the funded amount and loan amount
    NSNumber* fundedAmount = [loan objectForKey:@"funded_amount"];
    NSNumber* loanAmount = [loan objectForKey:@"loan_amount"];
    float outstandingAmount = [loanAmount floatValue] - [fundedAmount floatValue];

    // 3) Set the label appropriately
    humanReadble.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Latest loan: %@ from %@ needs another $%.2f to pursue their entrepreneural dream",
                         [loan objectForKey:@"name"],
                         [(NSDictionary*)[loan objectForKey:@"location"] objectForKey:@"country"],
                         outstandingAmount
                         ];

    //build an info object and convert to json
    NSDictionary* info = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          [loan objectForKey:@"name"], @"who",
                          [(NSDictionary*)[loan objectForKey:@"location"] objectForKey:@"country"], @"where",
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat: outstandingAmount], @"what",
                          nil];

    //convert object to data
    NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:info 
                                                       options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                         error:&error];

    //print out the data contents
    jsonSummary.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData
                                             encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

}

@end
```

Comment: You declare this `NSError* error;` but you never actually check the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is something wrong with my web service?

The easy way to tell is to access it with something other than your app. The command line program `curl` is a great tool for checking the results of a web service call. Even Safari can help here, especially if you enable the web inspector (Preferences->Advanced->Show Develop menu in menu bar). Really, anything that lets you see the results of a query should work.

Another way to check your service is to use a web proxy tool like Charles. You can set your device to use Charles as a HTTP proxy, and Charles will then be able to show you all the traffic between your app and the server.